# Newbie question about Continuous integration and selenium tests,

Tags: testing, automation, continuous-integration, build-process, selenium-rc

I'm very new to C.I. but I have recently inherited a project where Team City has just been implemented and I'm slowly getting my head around it. One thing we would like to do is run some Selenium Tests as part of the build process. I've created the selenium tests and can run them successfully via nunit-console on my development machine. The build server builds the project and then deploys it (A web forms application as it happens) to a staging server.

Before each selenium test we set the database to a known state, i.e. to only have certain records in place - that way each test is independent of the others. The problem is the staging server will be used by real "human" testers so this would cause them a problem with the database continually being reset (records being removed etc.) The question is should I really also deploy the application to a virtual directory on the build server and run the selenium tests against that and only deploy to the staging server if those tests pass?

Or have I got this stuff completely wrong? If so how do you do it in your organisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you **do not mix your automated and manual testing** by allowing your testers to access the server that is staged for your automated tests. This can cause false negatives both in your automated and your manual tests. These 'bugs' are indeterministic and more than likely never reproducible (a very bad news). This will cause you a lot of unnecessary 'bug reports' and build failures.

So here is what you can do...

In addition to your current setup, you can **create an extra staged server** for your manual testers. This is the ***least*** you should do. You should probably create **several** of them, **one for each tester**.

And here comes the rant...

In my current project we recently found out that our testers (we had ~10 of them) reused one server. They claimed that since our app is going to have multiple concurrent users, it was a good idea that while they are testing the individual functionalities, they are also testing how these functionalities act while multiple users are working on the same server. **WRONG!**

If multiple users are a concern, there should be test cases for the specific concerns. If functionality#1 can interfere with functionality#2, it should be specifically tested and not just be 'tested-by-luck'.

Before this was explained to our manual testers, we had many false bug reports due to the fact that one tester was simply stepping on another tester's toes. (e.g. tester1 deleted a record that tester2 introduced to the system, etc...). This created a lot of unnecessary bug reports and these bugs were never reproducible.

Sorry about the rant, I hoped this still helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good, we suspected that mixing automated and manual testing would be a bad thing. We intend to build the application on the build server (obviously) and run our automated selenium tests there, then deploy to the staging server for manual testing if all the automated tests run successfully. Thanks for your advice.